# Populate 2 tables with 2 sets of data when 1 field matches in both sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, postmessage

I'm using Josh Fraser's Backwards compatible window.postMessage() (http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage) and I'm having trouble.

I have 2 iframes on a page and both iframes send different data to the same parent page. In other words, there are 2 XD.receivemessage functions getting 2 different messages from 2 different iframes. Here's a shortened version of my code:

```
<iframe id="IFRAME1" src="https://www.DOMAIN.com/PAGENAMEFIRST.php"></iframe>
<iframe id="IFRAME2" src="https://www.DOMAIN.com/PAGENAMESECOND.php"></iframe>

<div id="firstTable">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Address</th>
   <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><!--this will be filled in by the data--></td>
   <td><!--this will be filled in by the data--></td>
   <td><!--this will be filled in by the data--></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div id="secondTable">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Twitter Handle</th>
   <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><!--this will be filled in by the data--></td>
   <td><!--this will be filled in by the data--></td>
   <td><!--this will be filled in by the data--></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//FIRST DATA PULL
var encodeUriFirst = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
var getMessageFirst = 'https://www.DOMAIN.com/PAGENAMEFIRST.php#' + encodeUriFirst;
$("#IFRAME1").attr('src',getMessageFirst);
XD.receiveMessage(function(getMessageFirst){
    var getDataFirst = getMessageFirst.data; 
    var getDataFirstEach = new Array();
    for(var a=0; a<getDataFirst.length; a++){ 
        getDataFirstEach = getDataFirst.split("~,~");
        $('div#firstTable table td:nth-child(0)').text(getDataFirstEach[0].replace(/[~]/g,""));
    }
}, 'https://www.DOMAIN.com');
//SECOND DATA PULL
var encodeUriSecond = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
var getMessageSecond = '//www.DOMAIN.com/PAGENAMESECOND.php#' + encodeUriSecond;
$("#IFRAME2").attr('src',getMessageSecond);
XD.receiveMessage(function(getMessageSecond){
    var getDataSecond = getMessageSecond.data; 
    var getDataSecondEach = new Array();
    for(var a=0; a<getDataFirst.length; a++){ 
        getDataSecondEach = getDataSecond.split("~,~");
        $('div#secondTable table td:nth-child(0)').text(getDataSecondEach[0].replace(/[~]/g,""));
    }
}, 'https://www.DOMAIN.com');
});
</script>
```

Please keep in mind that I've scaled back the code significantly. Each `getDataFirst` or `getDataSecond`

It actually works as far as getting the data from both iframes (send/receive both work). My data comes through in the format `~name~,~address~,~ID~` for the first set of data and `~email~,~twitter~,~ID~` for the second set.

I'm trying to get the data to populate the 2 tables. The `For` loops look for the ID in the table and if the ID matches, it fills in the other fields associated with that ID. In some cases, the ID from the first data set will be the same as the ID from the second data set. When that happens, the `for` loops place the data in both tables instead of the appropriate one. I'm wondering why this would happen since I'm specifically targeting the table inside either `$('div#firstTable')` or `$('div#secondTable')` for the output. For example:

```
$('div#firstTable table td:nth-child(0)').text(getDataFirstEach[0]);
```

inside the `For` loop is placing `getDataFirstEach[0]` into both the firstTable and secondTable tables?

Can anyone tell me why?

AS REQUESTED, HERE IS THE FULL JS:

```
var encodeUriGifts = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
var giftsMessage = '//www.DOMAIN.org/firstpage.php#' + encodeUriGifts;
$("#IFRAME1").attr('src',giftsMessage);
XD.receiveMessage(function(giftsMessage){
    var getDataGifts = giftsMessage.data; 
    var currentRecordGifts = new Array();
    var getGiftsLines = getDataGifts.split("|"); //LINES OF DATA ARE PIPE SEPARATED
    for(var bCnt=0;bCnt < getGiftsLines.length;bCnt++){ 
        var getGiftsEach = getGiftsLines[bCnt].split("`,`"); //EACH ITEM IS SEPARATED BY `,`
        for(var cCnt=0;cCnt < getGiftsEach.length;cCnt++){
            if (getGiftsEach[cCnt]!=="" && getGiftsEach[cCnt]!=="undefined"){
                currentRecordGifts[bCnt] = " <td class='giftamount'>"+getGiftsEach[1]+"</td><td class='giftdate'>"+getGiftsEach[2].replace(/[`]/g,"")+"</td>";
            }
            if (cCnt==2) {
                var thisGiftsID = getGiftsEach[0].replace(/[`]/g,"");
                $('#firstTable table td:contains("'+thisGiftsID+'")').closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').after(currentRecordGifts[bCnt]);
            }
        }
        if (bCnt==0){
            $('#firstTable table th:nth-child(3)').after('<th class="BBListingHeading DirectoryListingHeading" scope="col" style="white-space: nowrap;">Last Gift Amount</th><th class="BBListingHeading DirectoryListingHeading" scope="col" style="white-space: nowrap;">Last Gift Date</th>');
        }
    }
}, 'https://www.DOMAIN.org');

var encodeUriChanges = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
var changesMessage = '//www.DOMAIN.org/secondpage.php#' + encodeUriChanges;
$("#IFRAME2").attr('src',changesMessage);
XD.receiveMessage(function(changesMessage){
    var getDataChanges = changesMessage.data; 
    var currentRecordChanges = new Array();
    var getChangesLines = getDataChanges.split("|");
    $('#secondTable table tr td:nth-child(3)').each( function() {
        $('#secondTable table tr td:nth-child(3)').after('<td class="BBListingItem DirectoryListingItem" style="white-space: nowrap;"><ul class="changes"></ul></td>');
    });

    for(var dCnt=0;dCnt < getChangesLines.length;dCnt++){ 
        var getChangesEach = getChangesLines[dCnt].split("`,`");
        for(var eCnt=0;eCnt < getChangesEach.length;eCnt++){
            if (getChangesEach[eCnt]!=="" && getChangesEach[eCnt]!=="undefined"){
                currentRecordChanges[dCnt] = "<li class='change'>"+getChangesEach[2]+" ("+getChangesEach[1].replace(/[`]/g,"")+")</li>";
            }
            if (eCnt==2) {
                var thisChangesID = getChangesEach[0].replace(/[`]/g,"");
                $('#secondTable table td:contains("'+thisChangesID+'")').closest('tr').find('td ul.changes').append(currentRecordChanges[dCnt]);
            }
            if (dCnt==0){
                $('#changesdiv .DirectoryListingTable th:nth-child(3)').after('<th class="BBListingHeading DirectoryListingHeading" scope="col" style="white-space: nowrap;">Change Details</th>');
            }
        }
    }
}, 'https://www.DOMAIN.org');
```

Comment: You really should post the relevant JavaScript code, as that's where the problem's going to be.  I don't think your question title accurately describes the problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I've modified it. Hopefully I've made it clearer, but I'm not sure what the title should be. If you have a suggestion, I'll gladly change it again.

Comment: If that's what your HTML really looks like, then there's no way that the JavaScript statement you posted would update both tables.

Comment: I'm going to edit my original post again. At the end I'm going to paste everything. Just looking at it again, I'm guessing it has something to do with a for loop inside a for loop.